# Accessing add-on user data by webapp

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions, google-oauth, google-forms

I have a form add-on that accepts the user set fromdate and todate for accepting client responses.
I set that using properties service. Once the add-on is deployed, the addon user can set from and todate. After​ setting them The user instead of sending public form URL can send https://WEBappSCRIPTURL?FORMID=xxxxxxxxxxxx
Where WEBappSCRIPT is another apps script capable of accessing and determining whether the current time is between fromdate and todate. If between then redirect to public form URL for accepting response otherwise say closed to the client. The problem is how do I publish WEBappSCRIPT under the context of add-on user.

If I set as me then it will access developer fromdate and today. If I set to user accessing the app then it will make clients to authorize (non google users)

Comment: You can pass the end date in the URL, like so `https://WEBappSCRIPTURL?FORMID=xxxxxxxxxxxx&startdate=date1&enddate=date2` and ask the web app to check if the current date is between those 2 dates. Any reason you cannot do this?

Comment: Problem is not about passing parameters, it's about how to publish an app ? And in whose context whether developer (run as me) or user accessing the app? Date is taken from a file in users drive not developers drive file

Comment: If you pass the parameter you don't have to take the end date from a file, it will be passed by the link. Therefore you can run the script as a developer and still know the end and start date set by the user. The only other option is to use a trigger in your addon to stop accepting response after the end date. Using the following function [setAcceptingResponses(enabled)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setacceptingresponsesenabled)